# Create partitioned table from non partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Suppose I have internal orc non partitioned table in Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS non_partitioned_table(
        id STRING,
        company STRING,
        city STRING,
        country STRING,
        )
    STORED AS ORC;
```

Is it possible somehow create parquet partitioned table this way via cte like statement?

```
create partitioned_table PARTITION ON (date STRING) like non_partitioned_table;
alter table partitioned_table SET FILEFORMAT PARQUET;
```

This create statement doesn't work.

So basically I need to add column and make table partitioned by this column. I know that I can create table through the simple create table statement, but I need to do it within **CREATE TABLE LIKE** and the altered somehow

Answer (score 1):

Your table doesn't have a `date` column to begin with, so you're going to have to make a new one.

You might be able to [`ALTER TABLE non_partitioned_table ADD PARTITION`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions), but haven't tried that myself. If you want to try it, I would suggest the partition location be outside of the existing HDFS directory.

Anyways, the [`CREATE-TABLE-LIKE` DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable) does not support `PARTITIONED BY`

```
 CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name
 LIKE existing_table_or_view_name
 [LOCATION hdfs_path];
```

You need to copy the `DESCRIBE TABLE` schema from the first, then alter it and add the `PARTITIONED BY`, and optionally specify `STORED AS`. (`SET FILEFORMAT PARQUET` doesn't change the data type in-place).

Then, if you want the data in the new table, you need to `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE`

Comment: Thx for the reply, but could you pps clarify what do you (`SET FILEFORMAT PARQUET` doesn't change the data type in-place) ? After changing file format `show create table` is not the same as before

Comment: All you did was update an entry in the Hive metastore. `hdfs dfs -ls` the table location. The files don't magically change to parquet format